# Find best matching row in MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: regex, mysql

I have the following test string `engine/mail/key` and  a table which looks like this:

```
+-------------+
| query       |
+-------------+
| engine      |
| engine/pdf  |
| engine/mail |
+-------------+
```

I want to find the best matching row. Best match is specified by the most matching characters from the start of the string/row.

I have constructed a RegExp, but it of course matches all rows and won't give me any info about which matched the most chars/parts.
Regexp: `^engine(/mail(/key)?)?`

I had an other idea about using MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET` function like this:

```
`FIND_IN_SET(query,'engine,engine/mail,engine/mail/key')`
```

And order the result by it's output.

That would work, but it's not in any way a nice solution. Does anybody have an better idea about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use LIKE, but the other way around to what your probably used to.

```
select query
from table1
where 'engine/mail/key' like concat(query,'%')
order by length(query) desc
limit 1
```

Results:

```
mysql> select * from query;
+-------------+
| query       |
+-------------+
| engine      | 
| engine/pdf  | 
| engine/mail | 
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select query from query 
       where 'engine/mail/key' like concat(query,'%') 
       order by length(query) desc 
       limit 1;
+-------------+
| query       |
+-------------+
| engine/mail | 
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: This doesn't match anything. Also Ordering by the `LENGTH(query)` isn't sufficient, since there could well be a row like `engine/website` which would then be chosen over `engine/mail`.

Comment: Sorry, i've corrected the query so it will now run. Try it now to see if it's giving you the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks for this, much better than `FIND_IN_SET` hack! Using `LIKE` the other way arround like this is really a neat trick!