# MySQL match area code only when given the full number

Tags: mysql, odbc, asterisk

I have a database that lists a few area codes, area code + office codes and some whole numbers and a action. I want it to return a result by the digits given but I am not sure how to accomplish it. I have some MySQL knowledge but its not very deep.

Here is a example:

```
match     | action
_____________________
234       | goto 1
333743    | goto 2
8005551212| goto 3
234843    | goto 4
```

I need to query the database with a full 10 digit number -

```
query 8005551212 gives "goto 3"
query 2345551212 gives "goto 1"
query 3337431212 gives "goto 2"
query 2348431212 gives "goto 4"
```

This would be similar to the `LIKE` selection, but I need to match against the database value instead of the query value. Matching the full number is easy,

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE `match` = 8005551212;
```

First the number to query will always be **10 digits**, so I am not sure how to format the SELECT statement to differentiate the match of `234XXXXXXX` and `234843XXXX`, as I can only have one match return. Basically if it does not match the 10 digits, then it checks 6 digits, then it will check the 3 digits.

I hope this makes sense, I do not have any other way to format the number and it has to be accomplished with just a single SQL query and return over a ODCB connection in Asterisk.

Comment: Not sure if I understand entirely correctly, but, maybe [this answer helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667243/mysql-match-string-with-start-of-string-in-table)?

Comment: Are 10-, 6-, and 3-digit numbers the only options in the database?

Comment: First of all, the only way to deal with cases of multiple matches is to decide on their priority, so check the first match priority first, then the next etc. To do this look into the `CASE` operator. It allows you to perform several checks and just get the highest priority result into a single SQL query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find best matching row in MySQL (InnoDB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363858/find-best-matching-row-in-mysql-innodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT match, action FROM mytable WHERE '8005551212' like concat(match,'%')
```

The issue is that you will get two rows in one case .. given your data..

```
SELECT action 
FROM mytable 
WHERE '8005551212' like concat(match,'%')
order by length(match) desc limit 1
```

That should get the row that had the most digits matched..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 3 AS score,r.* FROM mytable r WHERE match LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING('1234567890',1,3),'%') 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS score,r.* FROM mytable r WHERE match LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING('1234567890',1,6),'%') 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 AS score,r.* FROM mytable r WHERE match LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING('1234567890',1,10),'%')
) AS tmp
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working -

```
SELECT `function`,`destination`
FROM reroute
WHERE `group` = '${ARG2}'
  AND `name` = 0
  AND '${ARG1}' LIKE concat(`match`,'%')
ORDER BY length(`match`) DESC LIMIT 1
```