# MySQL Query filter and order rows on match similar to job match or feature compare

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Google and Stack generally get me where I'm going but I'm stuck. I believe its because I'm not searching the right terms. There were many scripts that were close but either I didn't understand the result or it wasn't what I needed.

I believe I'm looking for "match" or "compare".

My table has both job providers and job seekers with very custom data..the great news is that every field is a set value (select / checkbox / radio )

here is the data available, there are about 17 skillset columns

```
 type   |  position  |  skillset 1 |  checkbox  | skillset 3 | salary
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  1,2,3     | Talent 3   |  50
 Seeker1|  Manager   |   Avail     |  avail     |  avail     |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  2         | Talent 3   |  50
 Seeker2|  Manager   |   Avail     |  avail     |  avail     |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  2,3       | Talent 3   |  60
 POSTED |  Manager   |   Needed    |  Needed    | Needed     |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  2         | Talent 3   |  50
 Seeker3|  Manager   |   Avail     |  avail     | NOT avail  |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
```

This was close but I wasn't sure and I couldn't get it to apply to my tables

[Find best matching row in MySQL (InnoDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363858/find-best-matching-row-in-mysql-innodb)

Since all values are select and not free text, it seems like a "feature compare" approach is the direction, but I call it a match because I want to return the matches in most/best order

I would expect to see this result when a column does not match or has less than one match in the column.

I would hope to show these in a "closest" order, I imagine that the only way to determine "best/closest" would be a column count of match / true?:

the columns compare like so:

```
 position   = Sales manager : Match
 skillset 1 = Talent1 avail : Match 
 checkbox   = 1 of 2 needed : Match (partial)
 skillset 1 = Talent3 NOT avail : NO Match 
 Salary     = < = >             : Match
 Columns match  = [4]
```

So this guy post a job

```
  Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  2,3       | Talent 3   |  60
  POSTED |  Manager   |   Needed    |  Needed    | Needed     |
  -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
```

His match result would be ordered from high to low:

```
 Seeker 1|  match    |   match     |  match (IN)|  match     | TRUE  [5]
 Seeker 3|  match    |   match     |  match (IN)|  NO        | TRUE  [4] 
 Seeker 2|  match    |   match     |  NO  (none)|  NO        | TRUE  [3]


 type   |  position  |  skillset 1 |  checkbox  | skillset 3 | salary
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  1,2,3     | Talent 3   |  50
 Seeker1|  Manager   |   Avail     |  avail     |  avail     |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  2         | Talent 3   |  50
 Seeker3|  Manager   |   Avail     |  avail     | NOT avail  |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
 Job    |  Sales     |   Talent 1  |  1         | Talent 3   |  50
 Seeker2|  Manager   |   Avail     |  avail     |  avail     |
 -------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------
```

So is a combination of "AND" & "OR"s going to do it, or does this require special MySQL "statements/functions". MySQL gets a bit complex for me.

### Update

Since all values are (select / checkbox / radio ) I can set values as numbers ( Manager = 1, Coach = 2, etc.)  But a string example would be great too because I have a feeling that I'll run into that in another table.

Comment: why do you many skill-set columns, it is better to create on more table for `skillset`.

Comment: the skillset is the users experience level. Are you suggesting I store an User's info in separate tables? ..that doesn't seem efficient, can you explain or have I misunderstood? - thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Fix your schema. See normalisation. You would have a separate table for user skill sets. User_id,skill_id

Comment: Yep, `Talent` should be in a different table. Presently, if a person's talents are (juggling, cooking, cat-stroking), then matching on a job requiring (cooking, cat-stroking, juggling) will be no matches unless you have additional logic to cope with the re-ordering. Plus, counting across columns is awkward, counting rows is easy and fast.

Comment: Okay, good suggestions... I have a users table already... So I can create separate table for their skill sets, search for the match, then left join there user info for only the match rows that are found.  How would I order them if I can't determine which row had the most matched columns??

Comment: @zzipper72 see for example https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Answer (score 1):

You probably need five tables. Consider the objects in your system:

- Job seeker (seeker_id, name, email address, telephone number, etc)
- Skill (skill_id, name)
- Position (job_id, name)

Now, how to link them together? Well, consider the relationships:

- A job seeker **has many** skills
- A position **has many** skills
- A skill **has many** jobs
- A skill **has many** seekers

Presently you're resolving these "has many" relationships by having multiple columns, but as noted in the comments, hard-won database experience tells people that you will quickly come unstuck this way. Your SQL queries will be awkward and, if you have a non-trivial amount of data, they will be slow as well.

Since the relationships are has-many in both directions, these are known as "many to many" relations. To resolve these, you need intermediate tables, like so:

- seeker_skill (seeker_id, skill_id)
- job_skill (job_id, skill_id)

So, to create a seeker skill, you insert the primary key of the seeker and the primary key of the skill into the `seeker_skill` table. This table does not need a primary key column, since the two foreign keys are sufficient to define a primary key in their own right.

The same goes for job skills.

---

This design advice will get you back on the right track. I haven't added any SQL, as I think it will be valuable for you to research that for yourself. If you have a database to hand, create the design I suggest, and populate it with some test data. Then, start writing a simple query, e.g. to list a specific user's or job's skills.

You could also use SQL Fiddle or similar tools, so that if you get stuck, you can ask a question with the exact test data and query you are stuck with.